# accentuated letters for natlink and dragonfly

Tags: python-dragonfly

I have a natlink setup, with dragonfly and aena on Dragon 13. It's working all well in English, and it's almost working for French.
I have a problem when a try to use accentuated letters in the grammar.

I get this error (natlink uniform6):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\NatLink\NatLink\MacroSystem\core\natlinkmain.py", line 322, in loadFile
    imp.load_module(modName,fndFile,fndName,fndDesc)
  File "C:\NatLink\NatLink\MacroSystem\_hello_world_aenea_fra2.py", line 26
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file C:\NatLink\NatLink\MacroSystem\_hello_world_aenea_fra2.py on line 26, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
root: Failed to load language-specific number module: global name 'GrammarError' is not defined
```

I also tried to put in encoding at the start of the file. But then I get another error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\NatLink\NatLink\MacroSystem\core\natlinkmain.py", line 322, in loadFile
    imp.load_module(modName,fndFile,fndName,fndDesc)
  File "C:\NatLink\NatLink\MacroSystem\_hello_world_aenea_fra2.py", line 34, in <module>
    grammar.add_rule(TestRule())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dragonfly\grammar\rule_mapping.py", line 137, in __init__
    c = Compound(spec, elements=self._extras, value=value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dragonfly\grammar\elements_compound.py", line 269, in __init__
    raise SyntaxError("Invalid compound spec: %r" % spec)
SyntaxError: Invalid compound spec: 'voici la t\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa9'
```

I tried with natlink version 4.1 tango to uniform6
I tried the tricks given in these links:

https://gitter.im/synkarius/caster/archives/2016/09/14

https://github.com/t4ngo/dragonfly/issues/11

If someone knows the right combinations of version numbers for each software in the pipeline with the right trick to make it all work please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the patch proposed by cheep on the second link in my post did work, I just made a mistake when applying it. I just re-applyed the patch on a fresh dragonfly install and it worked.

With all my tests i confirm that natlink-4.1uniform-7 works well with accent and that the culprit is dragonfly.

Answer (score 0):

This is been fixed via [Unicode/multi-language support for grammar specs #14](https://github.com/Danesprite/dragonfly/issues/14) in a Danesprite fork of dragonfly which is integrating fixes from the community. Hopefully fixes will be included upstream to t4ngo/dragonfly someday.

Let me know this resolves your issue.